# Getting data(text) from HTML elements(h2/span) of a webpage for Web Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a web application to get data from html page and I need the data of span inside the div class

**Example:**

```
<h2 class="doctor-specialties">
<span>
<a class="link grey" href="https://www.practo.com/delhi/dentist">Dentist</a>
</span>
, 14 Years Experience
</h2>
```

I want the data within `<span>` which is "*Dentist*" and the next value "*14 years experience*" which is outside the span but both the elements in the same class.

**As follow:**

Dentist
,14years experience

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the `text()` method and then get rid of any unneeded whitespace.

```js
$(function(){
    var string=$('.doctor-specialties').text().replace(/\s{2,}/g,"");
 console.log(string);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="doctor-specialties">
<span>
<a class="link grey" href="https://www.practo.com/delhi/dentist">Dentist</a>
</span>
, 14 Years Experience
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can simply get the text of the `h2`:

```
alert( $('h2.doctor-specialties').text() );
```